# How to fix: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: null is not an object". Event handler going crazy

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js, vuejs2, eventhandler

The Text Input is populated properly by "this.cameraPage", but as soon as I start to do changes in the the Input field, a Vue event handler complains that this.cameraPage is null

"this.cameraPage" is an object and is initialised in "created()" via a JSON API. It loads successfully and I can use the object as I wish for display purposes.

DATA

```
data() {
    return {
        cameraPage: {},
}
```

CREATED

```
async created() {
    let cameraPage = await this.$http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/camera/' + this.keyColumn + '.json')
    this.cameraPage = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cameraPage)).data
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" v-model="this.cameraPage.title"/>
```

I am a beginner to Vue and I have not purposefully added an event handler to the Input-text field so I guess this is some "Vue-Magic". It is hard for me to trouble shoot when I don't really know what to expect to happen.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I now know that you do not need to reference "this" when accessing properties in the Template. I removed the keyword and everything started to work again.